# Where did angels get their wings?

Tags: biblical-basis, angels, apocrypha

The Bible does not record angels having wings at any point, but this is a popular depiction of angels. Do any Christian groups teach that angels *do* have wings, in extra-biblical materials? Where does the idea come from?

Comment: Related: [What does the Bible say about the appearance of angels?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1986)

Comment: Everyone knows that angels get their wings when a bell rings!

Comment: It doesn't actually say this, but [Luke 2:13](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%202:13&version=NIV) refers to "heavenly hosts" which are often depicted as "floating in the air above the shepherds" (although according to the scripture, they could just as easily have been standing or lying on the ground, or climbing trees). But if they were in the air (as "heavenly hosts" might naturally be), they clearly need wings to stay there, right?! :)

Comment: No, Flimzy -- Superman floated and he didn't need wings. And he is less than an angelic being!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The Bible actually does indicate that angels have wings, as both cherubim and seraphim are angels.

> In the year that King Uzziah died I saw the Lord sitting upon a
>   throne, high and lifted up; and the train[a] of his robe filled the
>   temple. 2Above him stood the seraphim. **Each had six wings: with two
>   he covered his face, and with two he covered his feet, and with two he
>   flew.** 3And one called to another and said:  "Holy, holy, holy is the
>   LORD of hosts; the whole earth is full of his glory!"

***Isaiah 6:1-3 ESV***

---

> The cherubim shall spread out their wings above, overshadowing the
>   mercy seat with their wings, their faces one to another; toward the
>   mercy seat shall the faces of the cherubim be.

***Exodus 25:20 ESV***

---

> He put the cherubim in the innermost part of the house. And the wings
>   of the cherubim were spread out so that a wing of one touched the one
>   wall, and a wing of the other cherub touched the other wall; their
>   other wings touched each other in the middle of the house.

***1 Kings 6:27 ESV***

---

It is also assumed that the four living creatures are angelic beings, since it's hard to imagine what else they could be:

> And the four living creatures, **each of them with six wings**, are full of eyes all around and within, and day and night they never cease to say, "Holy, holy, holy, is the Lord God Almighty, who was and is and is to come!"

***Revelation 4:8***

Comment: Also, [Ezekiel 1](http://www.esvbible.org/Ezekiel%2B1/) and [10](http://www.esvbible.org/Ezekiel+10/).

Comment: yeah, since when are cherubim and seraphim angels?

Comment: @Nacht What do you think they are?

Comment: don't know. does that automatically make them angels? i suppose they both seem "celestial" and powerful, but other than that they seem completely different to me. ive even heard convincing arguments for cherubim and seraphim to be purely symbolic

Comment: @Nacht It seems at least reasonable to classify them as angels.  At least there is not strong evidence against the idea.

Comment: http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/34453/is-there-biblical-evidence-of-seraphims-being-angels/34575#34575 I asked a question on the subject and it clarifies that they aren't angels. They are a bit different.

Comment: I disagree. Cheribim and angels are entirely different and have entirely different roles. http://www.stevehusting.com/doubtbusters/2011/01/18/arent-cherubim-angels/

Comment: @Narnian, This answer is **misleading**. Sure the bible states that **some** angels have wings, but [not all do](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1990/102). Indeed it seems like the majority don't have wings. See http://www.gotquestions.org/angels-wings.html for more info.

Comment: @Narnian some time ago I gave a downvote to this answer. At that time [I didn't agree with what you said about cherubim and seraphim](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/74880/42957). I now do. If you will, edit your question so that I can upvote.

Answer (score 13):

It would make sense angels have wings if you are to accept that cherubim and seraphim are indeed angels. I don't. You are hard pressed to find anything in Scripture that indicates they are. It just isn't there. C andS beings are not messengers, comforters or have any attributes of the other angels except to say they worship and obey God.

The common accounts of angels (not C or S) never mention angels having wings. As a matter of fact they were always mentioned as being who appeared as though they are human.

How much sense would it make for Paul to implore his readers to be kind to everyone because they never know when they are entertaining angels? If an angels is standing beside me with wings, I think I would have inkling there might be an angelic being in front of me.​​​​​​

As far as the statement angels are "floating" proves they have wings, then you have to assume to the same for Jesus after he ascended into heaven or wings were needed for Elijah.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! You may want to check out our page on [how we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites). Thanks for posting.